# Sort an array by alphabetically by second word

Tags: php

I am sorting a multidimensional array that contains peoples names and some information aobut them. I'm using `asort($obj)` to sort it alphabetically by their first names (it comes first). It works great, only now I need to sort it by their last name, rather than first. However, the name in its entirety "Joe Smith" for example is under the "name" key. I need it sorted by last name, instead of first. How can I do this?

**EDIT**
It seems that I went about it in the wrong way. It ended up easiest to simply assign the first and last name from the DB to separate fields, rather than the same string.

Comment: right, or http://php.net/uasort if the keys are important

Comment: I know how to use those... but thats not the problem. The problem is that the first name and last name are basically just one string. I need to be able to traverse the string, find the last name, and sort it via that last name.

Comment: Impossible: [Names are hard](http://timothy.green.name/links/names-are-hard). Ask any librarian or anyone involved in bibliography.

Comment: @mdance Full names can not be parsed into parts. There are too many variations to do so reliably. You'll have to define yourself what makes up a first and last name in a string.

Answer (score 3):

Use `usort`:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    list($firstNameA, $lastNameA) = explode(" ", $a["name"], 2);
    list($firstNameB, $lastNameB) = explode(" ", $b["name"], 2);

    return strcmp($lastNameA, $lastNameB);
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not, so different than the previous answer. But, using a natural algorithm might be a good choice, on such situations.

```
$array = array( 
    array("first", "last"), 
    array("first2", "last2")
); //For an array of such format
function compare_last($a, $b) { return strnatcmp($a[1], $b[1]); } 
usort($array, 'compare_last');
```