# posts order by title second word

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a common question, i haven't been able to find a straightforward answer to. 
I want to generate a list of a custom post type titles. im using `'orderby' => 'title'` to have them display alphabetically. The titles are names and last names and i want to sort by the last name. I know i could create meta fields with seperated first and last names and order by the last name field. But i'd really like to see if there is no good method to `explode` the `'title'` and pass the second word in to `orderby'.

This is the basic code:

```
<?php
// Get the 'Actors' post type

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'actors',
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC',
'nopaging' => true,
'cache_results' => false,
'update_post_meta_cache' => false
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
echo '<li><img src="' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'_dtm_small_image', [0]) . '"><span>' . get_the_title() . '</span></li>';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Iv'e tried to:

```
$gettitle = get_the_title();
$lastname = explode(" ", $gettitle);
```

and then change to `'orderby' => $lastname[1],` . but it doesnt work. 
Is there no GOOD way to use the second word in the title to sort posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the loop, WordPress doesn't have an option.

What you can do is split the title and create an array:

```
$people = array();
while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
    list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(" ", get_the_title() ); // You can use list, since you said that's you only first and last name on the title.
    $people[] = $lastname;
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();

sort($people); // Sort the array Asc. NOTE: You can create a function to sort by sort or rsort, on input

foreach ($people as $last) {
    echo $last, "<br />"; // echo the last name
}
```

This is not very efficient, but it works. You should consider adding the two fields to WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress won't allow you to sort this way. You'll have to get the posts and sort the result yourself. I've found this answer and works ok in a simulation: [Sort an array by alphabetically by second word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484767/1287812).

Simulation:

```
<?php
function sort_so_10484704($a, $b)
{
    list($firstNameA, $lastNameA) = explode(" ", $a["post_title"], 2);
    list($firstNameB, $lastNameB) = explode(" ", $b["post_title"], 2);
    return strcmp($lastNameA, $lastNameB);
}

$arr = array( 
    0 => array( 'post_title' => 'Jonh Smith Lorem', 'post_content' => '1st item' ), 
    1 => array( 'post_title' => 'Abeline Zachs Ipsum', 'post_content' => '2nd item' ), 
    2 => array( 'post_title' => 'Carlos Xico Non', 'post_content' => '3rd item' ), 
    3 => array( 'post_title' => 'Kenn Tee Sequitur', 'post_content' => '4th item' ) 
);

usort($arr, "sort_so_10484704");
printf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($arr,true));
```

Result (`S -> T -> X -> Z`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Jonh Smith Lorem
            [post_content] => 1st item
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Kenn Tee Sequitur
            [post_content] => 4th item
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Carlos Xico Non
            [post_content] => 3rd item
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_title] => Abeline Zachs Ipsum
            [post_content] => 2nd item
        )
)
```

Untested:

```
$loop = get_posts( $args );
if( $loop ) {
    usort($loop, "sort_so_10484704");
    foreach( $loop as $post ) {
        echo '<li><img src="' . get_post_meta($post->ID,'_dtm_small_image', [0]) . '"><span>' . $post->post_title . '</span></li>';
    }
}
```

<sub>Check [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)</sub>